# fontDialog1 после смены шрифта не сохраняет предыдущий шрифт

Tags: c#, winforms, шрифты

Пытаюсь написать небольшой текстовой редактор. Уже сделал кнопки сохранения и открытия файлов,но возникла проблема с fontDialog.
После вызова fontDialog оно открывается,и даже изменяются шрифты,но если что-то напечатать с одним шрифтом,и сменить на другой,то старый не сохраниться.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Открытие";
            ofd.Filter = "Текстовые файлы (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.FilterIndex = 2;
            ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
                richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Title = "Сохранение";
            sfd.Filter = "Текстовые файлы (*.txt)|*.txt";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);
                sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void шрифтыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.Font = fd.Font;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: никто не будет ходить по вашим ссылкам  качать ваши файлы. Укажите весь необходимый код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сохраняете *плоский* текст из свойства `richTextBox1.Text` - он не содержит сведения о шрифтах и стилях.

Вместо этого сохраняйте/читайте данные из свойства `richTextBox1.Rtf`. Файлам с таким содержимым принято давать расширение rtf.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь при открытии сохраненного документа шрифты загружаются вместе с ним. Но осталось еще одно,при изменение шрифта с одного на другой,старый не сохраняется,а замещается новым.

Comment: @AkiraFurude естественно, вы же задаете шрифт всему контролу, а не отдельному фрагменту. [Читать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-font-attributes-for-the-windows-forms-richtextbox-control)